# can't see the footer after using postion absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

i am trying to add iframe with full page in wordpress but i am not able to see the footer when i add this code to the body as :

the code is :

```
<style type="text/css">
body {scrolling:no;
}
iframe {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}
</style>
<iframe src="http://www.sunnah.com" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

here is the link to see the result online at: http://www.dkir.com/hadiths/

need to fix it and want to see the footer right down...the iframe...

Comment: Can You explain a bit more? the page looks fine with me, the footer shows right after the `iframe`, And Why don't you use custom page template for your page? create a new file `page-hadiths.php` in your theme directory and add your `iframe` to it, it makes no sense to use `absolute` position just cover up your page...

Comment: Looks fine to me. I don't understand the problem. Can you explain further?